# WPF Image multi source change one by one cause memory leakage

Tags: wpf, image

I write my class which inherit Image and initialize the image source array when class is initialized,

when render is triggered, there is the code as following: after debug ,I found that the code

```
this.Source = _listOfImageSource[_currentIamgeIndex];
```

which will cause the memory leakage.

But I do not know how to correct this? how to release the memory before the source of Image changed.

any comments?

```
public void CompositionTarget_Rendering(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        if ((_listOfImageSource.Count > 0) &&
            _currentIamgeIndex < _listOfImageSource.Count)
        {

            this.Source = null;
            this.Source = _listOfImageSource[_currentIamgeIndex];    
        }
        _currentIamgeIndex += _stepInterval;

        if (_currentIamgeIndex > _listOfImageSource.Count) //stop the animmation
        {

            this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            _parentWindow.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            this.Source = null;
            CompositionTarget.Rendering -= CompositionTarget_Rendering;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure that all images in your `_listOfImageSource` collection are frozen. This should reduce memory consumption. And please note that it is not necessary to set Source to null right before assigning another value. That won't "release" anything.

Comment: Yes, I forzen the image when I created.var bitmapBingo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(pathBingo, UriKind.Absolute));

                bitmapBingo.Freeze();
                _listOfImageSource[0].Add(bitmapBingo);